# error while importing magento database via SSH

Tags: mysql, magento, command-line, ssh, terminal

I get the following error while trying to dump a magento database via SSH

```
ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 82966: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aloodawp/#sql-4136_fcf760`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELET)
```

im not really an expert with shell or mysql know the basics & never encountered this problem before

**SOLVED**

```
Are you getting this error when you dump, or when you are reading the dump back in? SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; and SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; around your dump should solve the problem.
```

Comment: Go to line 82966 of the script you're running and see what is the record that you're trying to add and what's the foreign key that gives you the trouble. Then manually insert the "father" record before you run the insert for the "child"

Comment: Are you getting this error when you dump, or when you are reading the dump back in? SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; and SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; around your dump should solve the problem.

Comment: add the foreign key checks worked thank you very much

Comment: @benmarks that would make a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to answer:

Are you getting this error when you dump, or when you are reading the dump back in?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

around your dump should solve the problem.